# Frequency in Large Numbers and Existence of Probability

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, law-of-large-numbers

Some process, which could be random or deterministic, is defined as a sequence with the finite and discrete outcome $S(n)$ = {$X_i \in \Omega$ | $i = 1, 2, 3, \dotsi, n$}. For example, $\Omega = \{E_1, E_2, E_3\}$ that has 3 possible outcomes.

If the existence of the probability measure for each of the 3 outcomes is not known, would the frequency of each outcome in large numbers, defined as below, converge to a fixed probability?
$$
f_i \equiv \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{N_i(n)}{n}, i = 1, 2, 3
$$

where $N_i(n)$ is the number of outcome $E_i$ $\in$ $S(n)$.

The law of large numbers does not apply here, because of at least two reasons.

1. The existence of a fixed probability for each of the 3 outcomes is not given.
2. The conditions for proving the law of large numbers are not guaranteed in the above process. For example, the independence among outcomes doesn't have to hold.

Is there any established mathematical theorem that can show that, under the more general conditions, there always exist a probability for each outcome, that the relative frequency in large numbers will converge to?

Comment: The frequencies don't have to converge, no.

Comment: Can we construct some specific counter-example to show that, the frequency may not converge? How may that frequency look like? For example, would it look like some drifting, or oscillating, values in $[0, 1]$? I'm trying to visualize how that could happen, even when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thanks very much!

Comment: It can oscillate. For example say there are just two outcomes 0 and 1. Retain an auxiliary "switch" variable as you go. If the switch is 1, pick 1. If the switch is 0, pick 0. If the current fraction of 1s exceeds 0.75, flip the switch from 1 to 0. If it falls below 0.25, flip the switch from 0 to 1. Then the sequence of fractions of 1s will drift back and forth between 0.25 and 0.75.